# Subsetting a unbalanced panel dataset to have at least 2 consecutive observations in R

Tags: r, subset, panel-data

I have an unbalanced panel dataset in R. The following will serve as an example:

```
dt <- data.frame(name= rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(3,2,3)), 
                 year=c(2001:2003,2000,2002,2000:2001,2003))

> dt
  name year
1    A 2001
2    A 2002
3    A 2003
4    B 2000
5    B 2002
6    C 2000
7    C 2001
8    C 2003
```

Now, I need to have at least 2 consecutive `year` observations for each `name`. Hence, I would like to remove row 4, 5, and 8. How do I best do that in R?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the comment below, I can make a bit clearer. If I had an extra observation (row 9) with `name`=`C` and `year`=`2004`, I would want to keep both row 8 and 9 along with the others.

Comment: What if row 9 contained `C 2004` ? Would you then want to keep it and row 8?

Comment: What if for some name you had this: `2000,2002,2003,2005,2007,2008`? Should you keep `2002,2003,2007,2008`? If so, that would result in non-consecutive years. Is that correct?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Yes, I would want to keep 2002,2003,2007,2008. Sorry that my question weren't clear, but I don't know how to say it better.

Comment: I have tried to come up with a way to do this that combines `plyr::ddply` (to operate chunk-wise on the `name` values) and `rle()` (to select consecutive rows only), but haven't got anything working yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My (hackish) way to do it would be:

```
is.consecutive = duplicated(rbind(dt,transform(dt, year=year+1), 
                                     transform(dt, year=year-1)),
                            fromLast=TRUE)[1:nrow(dt)]
```

`is.consecutive` contains a vector of booleans of the observations to be retained. For your example, this vector would be: `TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`

Finally, you can easily use this vector to subset your data.frame, e.g. with:

```
dt[is.consecutive,]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It requires the sorted name, year, right?

Comment: Not at all: both variables can be randomized along the rows :)

Comment: it seems like the solution here use no information about `name`, this may cause issue when you have data like (  id year
1  A 2000
2  A 2002
3  B 2003), the 2nd and 3rd would be `TRUE` from the solution above, but they are not from the same unit at the first place. any thought on how to solve this?

Comment: @JasonGoal try your example, it works fine... The information about name is kept through the time-shift transforms of: `transform(dt, year=year+1)` and `transform(dt, year=year-1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more (far too...?) convoluted alternative, where you can set the minimum length of runs of consecutive observations.

```
dt <- dt[order(dt$name, dt$year), ]

rl <- 2

do.call(rbind,
        by(dt, dt$name, function(x){
          run <- c(0, cumsum(diff(x$year) > 1))
          x[ave(run, run, FUN = length) >= rl, ]
        })
)
#     name year
# A.1    A 2001
# A.2    A 2002
# A.3    A 2003
# C.6    C 2000
# C.7    C 2001

rl <- 3

do.call(rbind,
        by(dt, dt$name, function(x){
          run <- c(0, cumsum(diff(x$year) > 1))
          x[ave(run, run, FUN = length) >= rl, ]
        })
)
#     name year
# A.1    A 2001
# A.2    A 2002
# A.3    A 2003
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dt,"name",function(x) {
    cons_idx=which(diff(x$year)==1)
    cons_idx=sort(unique(c(cons_idx,cons_idx+1)))
    x[cons_idx,]
})
```