# Individuals across time with missing data and gaps

Tags: r, time-series, data-cleaning

Cleaning data methods where an individual may or may not exists in a time period. I want to look at the individuals over time they might exists in the first time period or start in a time period other than the first. Individuals may have no data after a certain point, or have gaps in the data. Gaps in the data might not have a row of NAs, but instead might be missing entirely from the dataset. I want to be able to keep individuals that appear 'n' consecutive times, and have fewer than 'n' gaps in time(or by specific column name).

[Drop variable in panel data in R conditional based on a defined number of consecutive observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600716/drop-variable-in-panel-data-in-r-conditional-based-on-a-defined-number-of-consec)

The question above is similar to mine. However there are some periods where I have no data instead of all NAs. That is why counting NAs is not enough, I looked into measure the distance in time. It would have to reset for each group, and be difficult for groups not starting in t=1.

```
set.seed(5)
data<-data.table(y=rnorm(100))
data[sample(1:100, 40),]<-NA
data1 <- data.table(id = rep(1:10, each = 10),
           time = seq(1,10),
           x  = rnorm(100),
           z = rnorm(100))
data2<-cbind(data1,data)
data2$row<-1:nrow(data2)
data2a<-subset(data2,row<55|row>62 )
data3<-data2a[-sample(nrow(data2a), 5)]
View(data3)
count(data3$id)
    x freq
1   1   10
2   2   10
3   3   10
4   4    8
5   5   10
6   6    4
7   7    7
8   8    9
9   9   10
10 10    9
```

If I wanted gaps=0 and each id to have at least 5 observations. Then I would only keep ids 1,2,3,5,7,9,10. Since all of these groups have gaps=0 and I would also drop id 6, since it only has 4 observations.

Please also let me know where you learned the method, so I can follow that to learn more.

The out put:

```
set.seed(5)
library(plyr)
data<-data.table(y=rnorm(100))
data[sample(1:100, 40),]<-NA
data1 <- data.table(id = rep(1:10, each = 10),
                time = seq(1,10),
                x  = rnorm(100),
                z = rnorm(100))
data2<-cbind(data1,data)
data2$row<-1:nrow(data2)
data2a<-subset(data2,row<55|row>62 )
data3<-data2a[-sample(nrow(data2a), 5)]
View(data3)
dt<-data.table(count(data3$id))
dt2<-subset(dt, x!=6 &x!=4)
View(dt2)
dta<-data3[data3$id %in% dt2$x,]
dt3<-subset(dta, id!=8 |time < 7)
View(dt3)
print(dt3)
  id time           x           z           y row
  1:  1    1  1.17085642  0.21083288 -0.84085548   1
  2:  1    2  0.88484486 -0.03329921          NA   2
  3:  1    3 -1.31788860  2.02519699          NA   3
  4:  1    4 -1.64325094 -0.37078675  0.07014277   4
  5:  1    5  1.05925039 -1.57823445          NA   5
  6:  1    6  0.29008358 -0.12157195          NA   6
  7:  1    7 -0.40003350 -1.79667682          NA   7
  8:  1    8  1.24309578 -0.47559154 -0.63537131   8
  9:  1    9 -1.36641052 -0.88410232 -0.28577363   9
 10:  1   10 -1.44141330 -3.49805898          NA  10
 11:  2    1  1.34854906 -0.38198337          NA  11
 12:  2    2 -1.97852834  0.97768813          NA  12
 13:  2    3 -1.24095058 -0.55804095          NA  13
 14:  2    4 -0.10403913 -0.62645515          NA  14
 15:  2    5  0.73297296 -0.53045123 -1.07176004  15
 16:  2    6  0.45567962  1.89762159 -0.13898614  16
 17:  2    7  0.28807955  1.39554068 -0.59731309  17
 18:  2    8 -1.07369091 -0.74602587          NA  18
 19:  2    9  0.64874254 -0.30557308          NA  19
 20:  2   10  0.29916228  1.16967817 -0.25935541  20
 21:  3    1 -0.79599499  0.30438718  0.90051195  21
 22:  3    2 -0.02935340 -0.11749825  0.94186939  22
 23:  3    3  2.18023570 -0.06008553  1.46796190  23
 24:  3    4  0.95741847  1.47093895          NA  24
 25:  3    5 -0.30504863 -1.47814761  0.81900893  25
 26:  3    6 -0.41840334 -0.68361295 -0.29348185  26
 27:  3    7  0.09995405  0.46054060          NA  27
 28:  3    8 -0.22980962 -0.18150193          NA  28
 29:  3    9 -1.41521488 -1.15881631 -0.65708209  29
 30:  3   10 -0.39259886  0.40901892 -0.85279544  30
 31:  5    1 -2.62134481 -1.45565758  1.55006037  41
 32:  5    2  2.24625462  0.09378492          NA  42
 33:  5    3  0.09343168  0.98234922          NA  43
 34:  5    4  1.62728009 -0.59671016          NA  44
 35:  5    5 -0.51091755  0.07480485          NA  45
 36:  5    6 -0.65938084  2.19742943  0.56222336  46
 37:  5    7 -0.04019016  0.79502321 -0.88700851  47
 38:  5    8 -0.11869400 -0.53894221 -0.46024458  48
 39:  5    9 -0.01965686 -1.60128318 -0.72432849  49
 40:  5   10 -0.48567849 -0.73137357          NA  50
 41:  7    4  0.97438263  0.96691960  0.49636154  64
 42:  7    5 -1.26447348 -0.42332730 -0.76005793  65
 43:  7    6 -0.27742142 -0.83159945 -0.34138627  66
 44:  7    7 -0.18939869  1.39995727 -2.10232912  67
 45:  7    8 -0.38402495  0.01701396          NA  68
 46:  7    9  0.74058802  1.84749695          NA  69
 47:  7   10 -1.16833839 -0.68633938 -0.27966611  70
 48:  8    1  0.66753870 -0.21872403 -0.20409732  71
 49:  8    2  0.36623695  0.68259291 -0.22561419  72
 50:  8    3 -0.51494299  0.52413002          NA  73
 51:  8    4  0.45056824  0.08054998          NA  74
 52:  8    5 -0.18772038  0.05378554          NA  75
 53:  8    6  1.33906937 -0.73725899          NA  76
 54:  9    1 -0.11367818  1.21014609          NA  81
 55:  9    2 -0.29510083  0.18865716          NA  82
 56:  9    3  0.98916847  1.96249867  0.97552910  83
 57:  9    4 -0.77513181  0.13871194          NA  84
 58:  9    5  0.27589827 -1.57862735  0.67568448  85
 59:  9    6  0.41078165 -0.79702127          NA  86
 60:  9    7  0.61118316  1.22435388  2.38723265  87
 61:  9    8  0.93657072 -0.36533356 -0.47343201  88
 62:  9    9 -0.36754170 -0.16259028 -0.07577256  89
 63:  9   10  0.74037676  0.56047918          NA  90
 64: 10    2  0.62913443  1.23863449 -1.06241117  92
 65: 10    3  0.52774631  0.76743575  0.55703387  93
 66: 10    4 -0.47225530 -1.08740911  0.90073058  94
 67: 10    5  0.82371516  0.06750377  0.98994568  95
 68: 10    6 -0.42778825  1.60514057  0.38360809  96
 69: 10    7 -0.14264393  1.23222943 -0.34658381  97
 70: 10    8  1.41878305 -0.37911379 -0.54018925  98
 71: 10    9  0.48713390 -1.34986658 -0.18255559  99
 72: 10   10  0.60344145  0.36491810          NA 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try package dplyr and use this script:

```
 data3 %>% 
      data.frame() %>% # seems that with data.tables the group_by is lost after mutate
      group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(time_lag_1 = lag(time),
             time_diff = time-time_lag_1,
             N = n()) %>%
      summarise(max_time_diff = max(time_diff, na.rm=T),
                N = unique(N)) %>%
      filter(max_time_diff == 1 &
             N >= 5)
```

A little bit of explanation about how it works.

The first part:

```
data3 %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time_lag_1 = lag(time),
         time_diff = time-time_lag_1,
         N = n())
```

Calculates columns "time_lag_1" (shifted column "time") so you can compare the times of 2 consecutive rows (store the difference in column "time_diff") and calculates the number of observations of each "id". Of course, you have to group by "id" first:

```
    # id time           x           z          y row time_lag_1 time_diff  N
# 1   1    1  1.17085642  0.21083288 -0.84085548   1         NA        NA 10
# 2   1    2  0.88484486 -0.03329921          NA   2          1         1 10
# 3   1    3 -1.31788860  2.02519699          NA   3          2         1 10
# 4   1    4 -1.64325094 -0.37078675  0.07014277   4          3         1 10
# 5   1    5  1.05925039 -1.57823445          NA   5          4         1 10
# 6   1    6  0.29008358 -0.12157195          NA   6          5         1 10
# 7   1    7 -0.40003350 -1.79667682          NA   7          6         1 10
# 8   1    8  1.24309578 -0.47559154 -0.63537131   8          7         1 10
# 9   1    9 -1.36641052 -0.88410232 -0.28577363   9          8         1 10
# 10  1   10 -1.44141330 -3.49805898          NA  10          9         1 10
# 11  2    1  1.34854906 -0.38198337          NA  11         NA        NA 10
# 12  2    2 -1.97852834  0.97768813          NA  12          1         1 10
# 13  2    3 -1.24095058 -0.55804095          NA  13          2         1 10
# 14  2    4 -0.10403913 -0.62645515          NA  14          3         1 10
# 15  2    5  0.73297296 -0.53045123 -1.07176004  15          4         1 10
# 16  2    6  0.45567962  1.89762159 -0.13898614  16          5         1 10
# 17  2    7  0.28807955  1.39554068 -0.59731309  17          6         1 10
# 18  2    8 -1.07369091 -0.74602587          NA  18          7         1 10
# 19  2    9  0.64874254 -0.30557308          NA  19          8         1 10
# 20  2   10  0.29916228  1.16967817 -0.25935541  20          9         1 10
# 21  3    1 -0.79599499  0.30438718  0.90051195  21         NA        NA 10
# 22  3    2 -0.02935340 -0.11749825  0.94186939  22          1         1 10
# 23  3    3  2.18023570 -0.06008553  1.46796190  23          2         1 10
# 24  3    4  0.95741847  1.47093895          NA  24          3         1 10
# 25  3    5 -0.30504863 -1.47814761  0.81900893  25          4         1 10
# 26  3    6 -0.41840334 -0.68361295 -0.29348185  26          5         1 10
# 27  3    7  0.09995405  0.46054060          NA  27          6         1 10
# 28  3    8 -0.22980962 -0.18150193          NA  28          7         1 10
# 29  3    9 -1.41521488 -1.15881631 -0.65708209  29          8         1 10
# 30  3   10 -0.39259886  0.40901892 -0.85279544  30          9         1 10
# 31  4    1  0.94608855 -0.25820706  0.31591504  31         NA        NA  8
# 32  4    2  0.75177087 -0.26689944  1.10969417  32          1         1  8
# 33  4    4  0.80833598 -0.39345895          NA  34          2         2  8
# 34  4    5 -0.61453522 -1.84373725          NA  35          4         1  8
# 35  4    6  1.23825893 -1.54228827  0.95157383  36          5         1  8
# 36  4    7 -0.33809514 -0.58624036          NA  37          6         1  8
# 37  4    8  1.19636636 -0.85213891 -2.00047274  38          7         1  8
# 38  4    9 -0.44331838  0.77832456 -1.76218587  39          8         1  8
# 39  5    1 -2.62134481 -1.45565758  1.55006037  41         NA        NA 10
# 40  5    2  2.24625462  0.09378492          NA  42          1         1 10
# 41  5    3  0.09343168  0.98234922          NA  43          2         1 10
# 42  5    4  1.62728009 -0.59671016          NA  44          3         1 10
# 43  5    5 -0.51091755  0.07480485          NA  45          4         1 10
# 44  5    6 -0.65938084  2.19742943  0.56222336  46          5         1 10
# 45  5    7 -0.04019016  0.79502321 -0.88700851  47          6         1 10
# 46  5    8 -0.11869400 -0.53894221 -0.46024458  48          7         1 10
# 47  5    9 -0.01965686 -1.60128318 -0.72432849  49          8         1 10
# 48  5   10 -0.48567849 -0.73137357          NA  50          9         1 10
# 49  6    1 -1.44014752 -0.35574079          NA  51         NA        NA  4
# 50  6    2  0.14376888 -0.98541432  0.18772610  52          1         1  4
# 51  6    3 -1.23458665 -0.73117064  1.02202286  53          2         1  4
# 52  6    4 -1.75250121  1.46532408 -0.59183483  54          3         1  4
# 53  7    4  0.97438263  0.96691960  0.49636154  64         NA        NA  7
# 54  7    5 -1.26447348 -0.42332730 -0.76005793  65          4         1  7
# 55  7    6 -0.27742142 -0.83159945 -0.34138627  66          5         1  7
# 56  7    7 -0.18939869  1.39995727 -2.10232912  67          6         1  7
# 57  7    8 -0.38402495  0.01701396          NA  68          7         1  7
# 58  7    9  0.74058802  1.84749695          NA  69          8         1  7
# 59  7   10 -1.16833839 -0.68633938 -0.27966611  70          9         1  7
# 60  8    1  0.66753870 -0.21872403 -0.20409732  71         NA        NA  9
# 61  8    2  0.36623695  0.68259291 -0.22561419  72          1         1  9
# 62  8    3 -0.51494299  0.52413002          NA  73          2         1  9
# 63  8    4  0.45056824  0.08054998          NA  74          3         1  9
# 64  8    5 -0.18772038  0.05378554          NA  75          4         1  9
# 65  8    6  1.33906937 -0.73725899          NA  76          5         1  9
# 66  8    7  0.81621918  0.96643806  0.97348539  77          6         1  9
# 67  8    9 -0.65086272  0.18729094  0.18917369  79          7         2  9
# 68  8   10  0.72640902  0.27298575 -0.56288507  80          9         1  9
# 69  9    1 -0.11367818  1.21014609          NA  81         NA        NA 10
# 70  9    2 -0.29510083  0.18865716          NA  82          1         1 10
# 71  9    3  0.98916847  1.96249867  0.97552910  83          2         1 10
# 72  9    4 -0.77513181  0.13871194          NA  84          3         1 10
# 73  9    5  0.27589827 -1.57862735  0.67568448  85          4         1 10
# 74  9    6  0.41078165 -0.79702127          NA  86          5         1 10
# 75  9    7  0.61118316  1.22435388  2.38723265  87          6         1 10
# 76  9    8  0.93657072 -0.36533356 -0.47343201  88          7         1 10
# 77  9    9 -0.36754170 -0.16259028 -0.07577256  89          8         1 10
# 78  9   10  0.74037676  0.56047918          NA  90          9         1 10
# 79 10    2  0.62913443  1.23863449 -1.06241117  92         NA        NA  9
# 80 10    3  0.52774631  0.76743575  0.55703387  93          2         1  9
# 81 10    4 -0.47225530 -1.08740911  0.90073058  94          3         1  9
# 82 10    5  0.82371516  0.06750377  0.98994568  95          4         1  9
# 83 10    6 -0.42778825  1.60514057  0.38360809  96          5         1  9
# 84 10    7 -0.14264393  1.23222943 -0.34658381  97          6         1  9
# 85 10    8  1.41878305 -0.37911379 -0.54018925  98          7         1  9
# 86 10    9  0.48713390 -1.34986658 -0.18255559  99          8         1  9
# 87 10   10  0.60344145  0.36491810          NA 100          9         1  9
```

The second part :

```
summarise(max_time_diff = max(time_diff, na.rm=T),
            N = unique(N))
```

Calculates the maximum difference between consecutive times (this will spot your gaps) and keeps the N (unique value, as all N are the same for a specific "id"), for each "id":

```
# Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
# 
# id max_time_diff  N
# 1   1             1 10
# 2   2             1 10
# 3   3             1 10
# 4   4             2  8
# 5   5             1 10
# 6   6             1  4
# 7   7             1  7
# 8   8             2  9
# 9   9             1 10
# 10 10             1  9
```

Then the last part simply does your filtering and you get:

```
# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# 
# id max_time_diff  N
# 1  1             1 10
# 2  2             1 10
# 3  3             1 10
# 4  5             1 10
# 5  7             1  7
# 6  9             1 10
# 7 10             1  9
```

You can add `%>% select(id)` in the end to keep the IDs that satisfy your filters.

Comment: I am getting all blanks when I run it. Did you run into this problem at any point?

Comment: Blanks in which columns? I didn't have that problem. Any chance you have a different data3 format now? Different column names, column types, etc?

Comment: After running each part one at  a time "summarise(max_time_diff = max(time_diff, na.rm=T),
            N = unique(N))"produces a table with only five rows and max_time_diff =2 for all rows. Did you get that at any point?

Comment: You have to chain that part with previous ones. Did you just run that part by itself? Maybe I confused you. I was explaining what they do, but you have to run from the beginning every time. That's how the chaining %>℅ works. Hope this solves it.

Comment: data3a<- data3 %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time_lag_1 = lag(time),
         time_diff = time-time_lag_1,
         N = n()) %>%
  summarise(max_time_diff = max(time_diff, na.rm=T),
            N = unique(N)) :::That is what I was using then View(data3a)

Comment: Good that should have worked. I'll check it later. I'll create data3 again from scratch.

Comment: You are right my friend. I got that problem now and it's due to the fact the data3 is a data.table. Transform it to a data.frame and it should work. Just do data3 %>% data.frame() %>% group_by(id)......etc. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I did some more research and I saw that after "mutate" the grouping we specified using the "group_by" is lost when we work with a data.table, but it still exists when we work with a data.frame. I didn't expect that and I'm glad I found out via your question. Maybe someone more experienced can explain why this happens and if it's a reasonable thing.

Comment: Actually they've discussed it already : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363269/different-behavior-for-group-by-for-data-table-vs-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

"lapply" might be useful:

```
ID <- unique(data3$id)

n  <- lapply(ID, function(i){which(data3$id==i)})
tn <- lapply(n , function(i){data3$time[i]})

gapCount  <- lapply(tn, function(ti){sum(diff(ti)>1)})
maxPeriod <- lapply(tn, function(ti){max( c(ti[which(diff(ti)>1)+1],max(ti)) -
                                          c(min(ti)-1,ti[which(diff(ti)>1)])  ) } )

obsCount  <- lapply(n , length)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example 1: Remove all individuals with
#   at least one gap or
#   at most 4 observations.

keepTheseIDs_Ex1 <- which( gapCount==0 & obsCount>4 )
data_Ex1 <- data3[which(data3$id %in% keepTheseIDs_Ex1),]

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example 2: Remove all individuals with
#   at most 8 observations or
#   no connected period of length at least 5

keepTheseIDs_Ex2 <- which( obsCount>8 & maxPeriod>=5 )
data_Ex2 <- data3[which(data3$id %in% keepTheseIDs_Ex2),]
```

For each individual "ID[i]"

- n[i] is the list of row numbers, and
- tn[i] is the list of times associated to that individual.

If there is a gap in "tn[i]", i.e. "tn[i][j+1]-tn[i][j]>1", "diff[tn[i]" jumps at the index "j"
by the length of the gap plus 1, This is how the number of gaps are counted and collected in
the list "gapCount".

The connected periods start at the indices "which(diff(ti)>1)" and
end at the indices "which(diff(ti)>1)+1". So the differences of the corresponding times gives
the lengths of the connected periods. For each individual "ID[i]" the maximum length of the
connected components is the "i"-th item of the list "maxPeriod".

The individual "ID[i]" has "obsCount[[i]]" observations.

Comment: Would it be possible to transpose both gapCount and maxPeriod, then use A<-subset(gapcount,V=0) & B<-subset(maxPeriod, ti>4). Then use a something similar to dta<-data3[data3$id %in% dt2$x,] so that I could get the original data without groups with too few data point and missing data.

Comment: I extended my answer by two examples. "keepTheseIDs" is the vector of ID's that should remain in the table. Then "which(data3$id %in% keepTheseIDs)" is the vector of row numbers associated with these ID's.

Comment: I am getting this error I am not sure why, because I know there are missing time periods. Warning messages:
1: In max(ti) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(ti) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf:::Is it also possible to make the gap a rolling gap measure. Something that will find the first period and look for the first NA then delete the rest of the period that follows?

Comment: Using the table in the formulation of the question I didn't get any warnings.
The warning "no non missing arguments ..." means that "min" or "max" is appied
to a completely empty vector ("integer(0)"), not even containing NA's. But in the function
to calculate "maxPeriod", "ti" is equal to some element of "tn", i.e. "data3$time[i]"
for some "i" in "ID". This cannot be empty unless "n[i]" is empty, i.e. "data3"
contains no rows where "data3$id" is equal to "ID[i]".

Comment: I guess the column names in the data table were distinct from those in the example
given in the formulation of the question. When I renamed the "id"-column of the
data table the mentioned warnings indeed appeared. So try again using the correct
column names.

Comment: Did you at least check if your column names were correct?